# In camel how to generate alert mail when active mq is down

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using apache camel 2.x and active amq version 5.x
I have an amq where I am putting some message. Now I want to trigger an alert mail using camel when ever the amq is down .

here is my configuration details:
Code  in bean

```
        <bean id="activeMQ" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" lazy- init="true">
                     <property name="brokerURL" value="some url" />
                 </bean>
```

Broker URL :failover:(tcp://abc.abc:56789,tcp://abc.abc:1234)?randomize=true

Comment: You are probably better off using a proper system monitoring tool like Zabbix or one of its alternatives to monitor the health of your infrastructure.

Comment: You could create a timer route which sends some test message to the AMQ & has an exception handling clause where you could send the email alert. But as Ralf said checking system availability should not be done as part of you code, a monitoring tool would do it much efficiently & easily.